# Application crashes when passing ViewModel to the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

1. When I pass the view model to the method it crashes but it works with FormCollection or not passing anything to the onpost method.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public ActionResult Update(CustomerInformation model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //save
        var UpdateRecord = customerServices.Update(model);
        if (UpdateRecord)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }
    }
}
```

```html
@model Customer.Models.CustomerInformationDetails
@using Customer.Models.CustomerInformation

@{
    var customerName = Model.Name;
    ViewData["Title"] = customerName;
}

<h1>Edit information for @customerName</h1>
<hr />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update",
              "Customer",
              FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Introduction", "Introduction:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Introduction, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Contact Person", "Contact Person:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactPerson, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Does it give you an error?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error. 
I have a breakpoint in the method and it never hits that and just close the browser. But when I don't pass the view model to the method it works fine and hit the breakpoint.

Comment: Have you checked the "Output" window after it crashed to see if there was an error logged?

Comment: It just shows me the list of all the dll that the iisexpress loaded and finally:
The program '[5000] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
I don't think there is anything to do with the iisexpress as it works without the view model perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
return View(model)
```

outside of your if statement.

Currently if it fails it has nothing to return.

Comment: I do have a return outside the if statement. It's just that it's not copied in the question.
Here is the complete View Model Code:
[HttpPost]
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public ActionResult Update(CustomerInformation model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //save
        var UpdateRecord = customerServices.Update(model);
        if (UpdateRecord)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }
    }
return View(model);
}